# How do I connect NTFS Seagate External Drive to Airport Extreme via a USB splitter?

Tags: external-hard-drive, airport-extreme

I recently bought an Airport Extreme v. 7.6 and would like to connect two external hard drives via a USB splitter.  One is a Western Digital Mac formatted drive and one is a Seagate 1 TB FreeAgent Drive.  The Seagate is NTFS formatted but works on my Mac via a NTFS for Mac Utility which was installed as a part of the drive.

When I click on Airport Utility, both the Seagate and the Western Digital HDs are appearing, however, only the WD drive appears in my Finder under the base station link under Shared items.  Is there a way to get the Seagate to appear as well?  It works fine if I plug the Seagate directly into my Mac, and it appears in Airport Utility, so the base station seems to be recognizing it - I just can't access the contents through the finder.

Answer (score 2):

Just stopping by and i have the response for your problem:

USB hard drives on Airport Extreme USB port can only be HFS+ or Fat 16 or Fat 32. All the other format (NTFS, EXT2 or 3 or 4) cannot be recognized.

So you can see the mac formated one (HFS+) but not the NTFS one.

The problem is a limitation on the Airport.

Answer (score 0):

An USB **splitter** will not work when you connect more than one USB device, except when you are not using any data. (e.g. when you only need to use up to 100mA in total to charge things).

A USB hub might work, though you would halve the speed if you accessed both drives at the same time. (e.g. when copying from one external harddrive to the other external harddrive).